# Insert into sql server from asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I've text box and button. I'm trying to insert value of textbox in to sql table while clicking the button.,
It seems like I'm doing some mistake which I can't able to find

Here is my code

```
<td><asp:TextBox ID="Master_product_txt" runat="server" CssClass="Textboxbase" ClientIDMode="AutoID"></asp:TextBox></td>
<td><asp:Button ID="master_pro_name_add"  runat="server" Text="ADD" BackColor="#E2AFFE" Font-Bold="True" Font-Overline="False" ForeColor="#4A0095" OnClick="master_pro_name_add_Click" /></td>
```

my C# code

```
protected void master_pro_name_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   string Con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conn"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(Con);
            sqlconn.Open();
            SqlCommand objcmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into PRODUCT(PRODUCT_NAME) Values('" + Master_product_txt.Text + "')",sqlconn);
            sqlconn.Close();
        }
```

and my connection string

```
<add name="Conn" connectionString="Data Source=PC-GN\KASPLDB;Initial Catalog=STOCK;User ID=sa;Password=****" />
```

Comment: "Execute" your command (`objcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`). Simply opening a connection and closing it will not be sufficient. Refer to some basic ADO.NET tutorials.

Comment: @RJ10 use parameterized query

Answer (score 3):

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(string Con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conn"].ConnectionString;))
     {
      string result;
      var cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into PRODUCT(PRODUCT_NAME) Values (@mastertxt)",con);   
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mastertxt",Master_product_txt.Text);
      con.Open();
      int flag = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      con.Close();
      if (flag == 1)
        {
         result = "Add record";
        }
      else
        {
         result = "Fail Insertion";
        }
       return result;

     }
```

Comment: Please read Can we stop using `AddWithValue` - http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/ .

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to add

```
  objcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

You must used parameterized query

---

Here's what i do, by creating storedProcedure

**Sql:** creating Storedprocedure

```
CREATE PROC insertRecord(
    @prdName VARCHAR(150) 
)
 AS BEGIN
     INSERT INTO PRODUCT(PRODUCT_NAME) 
     VALUES (@prdName)
 END
```

**Code behind:**

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(cn.ConnectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "storedProcedureName";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@col1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = value1;
        cmd.Connection = cn;
        cn.Open();
        int temp = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (temp > 0)
        {
            Response.Write("Record added successfully");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Woops something went wrong!");
        }
        cn.Close();
    }
}
```